# Perform single optimization step with Scipy optimizer

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am solving a problem of minimizing a function using the BFGS-optimizer available in in Scipy from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html.
In certain cases I would like to perform just a single optimization step with my Scipy optimizer. I would think that this should be easy, but I cannot find any way to do it based on the documentation available in the link. There is an option 'maxiter', which I have tried to set to 1. But this seems to be number of internal evaluations of the BFGS algorithm before it returns the new function value and hence not the number of function evaluations. Does anyone have an idea about how to solve my problem?

Kind regards

Comment: Unless you have analytical gradients, no optimizer can perform an optimization step with a single function call. BFGS should show your expected behavior if you DO have analytical gradients.

Comment: A single iteration is very different from a single function evaluation.